# What would happen when you cast spells meant for objects on humans?

Tags: harry-potter, spells

We know that certain spells usually meant for objects can also work on humans, for example:

- *Transfiguration*, when Moody Transfigured Draco into a Ferret
- *Vanishing spells*, when Dumbledore disappears/hides
- etc.

**What could happen if a spell meant specifically for an inanimate object misfired and hit a human instead?**

i.e. If you say the "turn vinegar to wine" spell, what would happen if it hits a human?

Comment: I would guess that any vinegar contained in the human would turn to wine, but is just a guess and just my opinion.

Comment: we dont know exactly if its the same spell when used on a human or on an object nor any reference, we also dont know if those spells will even work on humans and again no canon to back it up, since alot of those spells happen after rowling stops giving use alot of incantations we are unable to determine if it can happen, or if its the same spells, therefor we cannon determine what will happen. from early spells we know they are exact and specific, their are some general spells such as summoning, but others are very specific.

Comment: This is a perfectly answerable question within the scope of canon for those who are willing to put the time and effort into doing a bit of research. Just because one doesn't know the answer to a question right off the bat doesn't mean that someone else doesn't have the knowledge to give a great answer or that the information to answer doesn't exist. I'm so weary of users rushing to close legitimate or potentially legitimate questions as "too broad" or "opinion-based" just because they don't happen to know the answer offhand. In the review queue, I voted to keep this question open. :)

Comment: "Accio eyeballs!" would be interesting too

Comment: I think this is an interesting question, but your examples aren't really correct. Transfiguration and Vanishing aren't really 'object' spells. They are more common on objects (because that's easier than on humans), but it's not like Moody took an object spell and changed it so he could use it on Draco.

Comment: I think the Transfiguration spell Moody used on Draco was meant for human Transfiguration.  I'll have to find the quote in Goblet itself that human Transfiguration is the most difficult branch of Transfiguration, probably discussed when one of the contestants turns himself to a half-shark for the second task.

Comment: *Accio* everyone's *eyeballs!* (What have I done?)

Comment: @Dacio -- That's a lot of eyeballs! Where will you keep them all? ;)

Comment: @Bobo I did mention that these 'known' spells are more commonly used for objects; also, these are not my examples.

Comment: @Lora Feel free to edit out the examples which I added. If my edits change your intent, then it can be seen as vandalism. Just though a bit of examples might help :)

Comment: @Slytherincess eye hadn't thought about it, but but a forward looking pupil who had the nerves could stay on the ball and  envision a solution before the whole thing became too bloodshot. Retina.

Answer (score 2):

To simply answer your question, based on your example, of vinegar to wine nothing would happen should it be used on a human. spells are very specific in nature. the way the wording is, the stressing of the syllables, as well as hand movement all can effect the spell. those are facts. so its easy to assume that if magic is that precise and finicky that the objects may also play a part.

we have group spells, specific spells, and vague spells.

a group spell example would be such as a the hover charm,(alot of charms actually) summoning charm, it appears to allow any object be summoned to you, it also may allow you to summon a human ( reference to the yule ball in hp4 where harry thinks he sees to guys summon 2 guys over to them) this is speculative though as weve seen instances when summing a person to you might be ideal, but wasn't used.

Next we see specific spells, lumos (light from your wand), Alohomora (unlocks doors), now these spells are seen only used in specific ways. however could alohomora be used to unbutton that hot girls shirt across the room? i would say no, as A. it would be far to cool, B. its a specific spell made for unlocking doors/locks. I would say based on examples in the books that some transfiguration spells fall into this category, especially a vinegar to wine spell.

finally we have vague spells (dont have the spell names handy but) the spell used to destroy or blast a hole (used in the maze to get through a wall in hp4) can this be used on a human to blast a hole through them? we have the spells to enlarge or shrink i think we have seen examples of hands ears noses being changed with this spell(tho not implicitly stated that these spells were used) can these be used macro'ly on a human to enlarge the entire human, or shrink yourself tiny, it can be used this way on animals but on humans? 
i think the rest of the transfiguration spells fall into these, such as turning a human into a ferret, is it a specific human transfiguration spell, or is it the same spell to turn a weasel into a ferret? spells arnt given in the book, and theirs no clues to alot of these spells.

Comment: Hover charm is different for living and non-livings ...